# How to pluralize an acronym which ends in 'S' correctly?

Tags: acronyms

When using the `acronym` package, how can you [correctly pluralize](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/503/12232) an acronym which ends on 'S'?

Take the acronym: *OS - operating system*

It should be pluralized as *OS's*, but is pluralized as *OSs* when using `\acp`.

Comment: Note that while *OS's* is an acceptable plural, it's not the only right answer -- check your style guide if one applies (CMOS and NYT say yes, APA says no, the Guardian implies no by example).  [English.stackexchange discussion](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/plurals-of-acronyms-letters-numbers-use-an-apostrophe-or-not) (not the first, probably not the last).

Comment: Echoing @ChrisH but note OP's (apostrophe indicating possession there) link - https://english.stackexchange.com/a/58994/92427  gives specific mention of OS

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To define plural exceptions, you can use `\acrodefplural`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}

\acrodefplural{OS}[OS's]{Operating Systems}

\begin{document}

\acp{OS}


\begin{acronym}
\acro{OS}{Operating System}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

[image]

More information can be found on Section **2.3.1 Non standard and foreign plural forms** of the `acronym` package documentation (see [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/acronym)).

Comment: It's so difficult to google for this stuff. I remember googling for "latex acronym plural exception" and nothing interesting showed up. Perhaps it's just a matter of knowing where to look, and TeX is a great help! Thanks.

Comment: @StevenJeuris: You're welcome! Now, thanks to your question, if I google for "latex acronym plural exception", this question appears in the second place, so now other users will find a quick solution ;-)

Comment: When I use this solution the usages of the plural form of that acronym no longer gives a link to the acronym list. Why is that? Can it be solved?

Comment: I have the same questions as @Kajsa.

Comment: I have the same questions as @JCML

Comment: Keep in mind that it is optional to define the plural acronym `[OS's]` because if you do, the hyperlink to the `OS` part of `OS's` will no longer show up

Answer (score 5):

To also have the plural show up as a link to the acronym list, enter two acronym entries similar to as such:

```
\acro{TSE}{transmissible spongiform encephalopathy}
\acrodefplural{TSE}{transmissible spongiform encephalopathies}
```

Then make sure you reference the acronym in the text body as such:

```
\acp{TSE}
```

This will now enter in the text with a link to the acronyms list as such:

"... transmissible spongiform encephalopathies (TSEs) ..."

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Isn't this the same solution as in @Gonzalo's answer (just using a different acronym)?

Comment: no @Gonzalos answer gives no hyperlink

Comment: When I use \acrodefplural I cannot see the acronym in the list of acronyms and it does not make the hyperref link to it.