# plural of acronym package not working well

Tags: acronyms, plural

I have:

```
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
```

on my preamble.

Then I defined my acronym, as follows:

```
\acro{BP}{Business Process}
```

But, when I used it on my text I get:

```
Business Processs (BPs)
```

Does anyone know how I can correct this problem?

Comment: found the answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38558/how-to-pluralize-an-acronym-which-ends-in-s-correctly

Comment: Since you seem to have found your anser here: [How to pluralize an acronym which ends in 'S' correctly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38558/how-to-pluralize-an-acronym-which-ends-in-s-correctly), I vote to closer your question as a duplicate of the before mentioned.