# acronym package - acroplural not working in acronym environment

Tags: hyperref, acronyms, hyperlink, plural

I'm trying to use the `acronym` environment from the [`acronym` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/acronym) to typeset a list of acronyms in my document. I want to specify a non-standard plural form for an acronym using `\acroplural` (which, according to the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/acronym.pdf), "is meant
to be used in the acronym environment"), but doing so is giving me an error message.

### MWE

#### Document

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acronym,hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
    \acro{POI}{point of interest} \acroplural{POI}{POIs}{points of interest}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

#### Error Messages

```text
LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `acro:POI' on page 1 undefined on input line 8.


LaTeX Warning: Hyper reference `acro:POI' on page 1 undefined on input line 8.

document.tex:8: Undefined control sequence.
\hyper@@link ->\let \Hy@reserved@a 
                                   \relax \@ifnextchar [{\hyper@link@ }{\hyp...
l.8 ...}{point of interest} \acroplural{POI}{POIs}
                                                  {points of interest}
document.tex:8: Argument of \AC@acroplurali has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.8 ...}{point of interest} \acroplural{POI}{POIs}
                                                  {points of interest}
Runaway argument?
{POI}{\hyper@link@ }\def \reserved@b {\hyper@link@ [link]}\futurelet \ETC.
document.tex:8: Paragraph ended before \AC@acroplurali was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.8 ...}{point of interest} \acroplural{POI}{POIs}
                                                  {points of interest}
[1] (./document.aux)
```

### Related

[How to pluralize an acronym which ends in 'S' correctly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38558) is a similar question, but it asks about defining a non-standard plural form *outside* of the `acronym` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omitting `hyperref` your code compiles but inserts a spurious `points of interest`, it would also lead `\aclp{POI}` to give `POIs` rather than `points of interest`.

This is because the second argument of `\acroplural` (the short-form plural) is an optional argument and if supplied should be supplied as `\acroplural{POI}[POIs]{points of interest}`. From the package documentation:
[image: Page 6 of the acronym package documentation, with the square brackets around the "short plural" argument to \acroplural highlighted.]
In this case it is not necessary to supply it as only the long-form plural is not given by appending an `s`. This issue is not specific to `\acroplural` or the `acronym` environment, it would also occur in `\newacroplural` and `\acrodefplural` which use the same syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}
    \acro{POI}{point of interest} 
    \acroplural{POI}{points of interest}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

However with `hyperref` there is a second issue if the optional argument is not supplied

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}
    \acro{POI}{point of interest} 
    \acroplural{POI}{points of interest}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

giving the error

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> \hyper@@link ->\let \Hy@reserved@a 
>                                    \relax \@ifnextchar [{\hyper@link@ }{\hyp...
> l.8     \acroplural{POI}{points of interest}
> ```

This can be resolved as you noted in the comments by explicitly supplying the optional argument as `\acroplural{POI}[POIs]{points of interest}`.
However the documentation of acronym seems quite clear that this should not be necessary which would make this a bug in the package.

As `\acroplural{POI}{POIs}{points of interest}` is parsed as giving `POI` and `POIs` as the acronym and acronym long-form plural, and then just having the group `{points of interest}` following it (this is not swallowed as an argument as you can see by omitting `hyperref`). You therefore end up seeing the more severe `hyperref`-related error even though the first mistake was in syntax of `\acroplural`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the second argument is optional, but can you please clarify your answer? I'm having a similar problem when I delete the second argument altogether, changing the line in the `acronym` environment to `\acro{POI}{point of interest} \acroplural{POI}{points of interest}`. I can get the document to compile by using `\acro{POI}{point of interest} \acroplural{POI}[]{points of interest}`, but then the short plural form doesn't show up at all. Do I have to do `\acro{POI}{point of interest} \acroplural{POI}[POIs]{points of interest}` (you said that was unnecessary)?

Comment: `\acroplural{POI}[]{points of interest}` supplies an optional argument which is empty (and so the short plural is set to be nothing), `\acroplural{POI}{points of interest}` does not supply an optional argument and so the short plural defaults to POIs. This is how optional arguments typically work in LaTeX, [\newcommand argument confusion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117358/106162) may help further understanding.

Comment: I understand that `[]` is supplying a blank optional argument to the `\acroplural` command—sorry if I wasn't clear. My point in my previous comment was that if I *omit* the square brackets altogether (which, as you said, is "how optional arguments typically work in LaTeX"), then *it still doesn't work*. You can see this if you change the MWE to read `\acro{POI}{point of interest} \acroplural{POI}{points of interest}` and try to compile.

Comment: Oop, sorry didn't read your comment carefully enough, and I must've removed hyperref in tracing the issue.  If `\acroplural{POI}[POIs]{points of interest}` works it works, my reading of the documentation is definitely that `\acroplural{POI}{points of interest}` *should* work, so if it doesn't you should raise an issue (https://github.com/oetiker/acronym/issues).